# Switch from native-activity to a normal java activity

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am creating a game for android. The native activity is used for the main part of the game but i want to be able to switch to a java activity. I've searched almost all android header files but i cant find any function which allows me to switch activity.

Is there some way i can start a java activity?

Answer (score 0):

The [`am` command](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/ADB_Shell_Command_Reference) from the shell can be used to send Intents to Actvities. In the source code of [SuperUser](http://code.google.com/p/superuser/) you can find, for instance:

```
char sysCmd[1024];
sprintf(sysCmd, "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.koushikdutta.superuser/com.koushikdutta.superuser.SuperuserRequestActivity --ei uid %d --ei pid %d > /dev/null", g_puid, ppid);
if (system(sysCmd))
  return executionFailure("am.");
```